# ¿ QUÉ SIGNIFICA DAILY HITS?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

¿A qué hace referencia? Estoy haciendo proyecto en host gratuito para pruebas, y cada día que entro en el cpanel me aparece la barra de estadística de daily hits con un porcentaje alto, realmente no sé a qué hace referencia.

Comment: literalmente es "Exitos Diarios" así que posiblemente se deba a las paginas que mas visitas reciben, has intentado clickear ahí? que te muestra

Comment: Fui a la parte de account statistics, salen unas graficas (dalily hits use, daily hits used, average daily hits used)

Comment: Parecen ser estadisticas de Uso, El contrato de dominio con el que cuentas posiblemente cuente las visitas que tiene tu sitio y te esta dando unas estadisticas de lo mismo.

Answer (score 2):

**Daily hits**, hace referencia a como lo indica su nombre, hits diarios a un contenido.
Se refiere a la cantidad de archivos descargados de un sitio determinado, por ejemplo al cargar un sitio se descargan regularmente archivos como son hojas de estilo (.css), imagenes, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que hablamos de estadísticas, existen 2 conceptos que creo son importantes a comentar.

**Page Views** (Vistas de página): Se produce cuando es cargada una pagina de tu sitio. Un Page View puede producirse cuando la misma página es cargada varias veces, por ejemplo si cargas en 10 ocasiones, se producen 10 Page Views.

y

**Unique Visitor** (visitante único) : es un usuario individial que accede al sitio.
A diferencia de Page Views, si accedemos en 10 ocasiones al contenido, se determina como un visitante único a menos que se acceda desde otro dispositivo o navegador. Si visita desde otro equipo, dispositivo o navegador contara como otro visitante único. Un Unique Visitor puede ser determinado por el id del dispositivo, la ip o la cookie del navegador que usa.

---

Como ejemplo de los 3 conceptos, una gráfica y datos de un sitio generados por AwStats:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, quedó aclarada mi duda!